# Do you think that Principal component Analysis for Mixed Data is able to make a classification for groups?

Tags: classification, pca, mixed-type-data

In fact, I used Principal component Analysis for Mixed Data, for that I have used PCAmix in R as it is shown in [this tutorial](http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~mchave100p/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/chavent_useR_2015.pdf):

I have some results as it is shown in page 13 [image]

But this result doesn't mean that I have any classification, for that I am asking If PCAmix is able to make classification?  If it is  not , how to make classification after using PCAmix please?

Comment: I think you are going to need to edit your question to give us more details about the context and why you think it can or cannot.

Comment: When you edit your question please note that PCA does not classify data, it reduces dimensions so you have to be more clear

Comment: @Cherny  thank you for your answer , could please see the edited question?

Comment: @mdewey thank you for your answer , could please see the edited question?

Comment: The short answer is "no," even PCA for mixed data will not do this. If you think in terms of a matrix of data consisting of variables (features, fields, columns, etc.) and observations (rows in the matrix), PCA creates linear components from the variables. Cluster algorithms create groupings from the observations. One approach to combining them that is appropriate for mixed data are finite mixture models such as latent class models. Good intros to this class of models can be found on the proprietary software website for *Latent Gold* developed by Statistical Innovations. It has many papers.

Comment: What is "mixed data"? Mixed data type (interval, categorical...)? Gaussian mixture? Else?

Comment: @ttnphns  I have  categrical and quantitaf data.

Comment: @DJohnson  , I have  categrical and quantitaf data and I found in this presentation Variable Clustering and Mixed Data. The ClustOfVar package   in page 27 that:                                                                                           For numerical data:
,→ Standard methods (among others): functions kmeans and
hsclut in the R package stat.
,→ Standard specific R packages (among others): cluster,
fastcluster.
For categorical or mixed data type: standard methods on
principal components of PCAmix for instance.

Comment: Ok. What's your point?

Comment: @DJohnson  I find that is unclear, I did the PCAmix but It does not give me any classification , so maybe I must convert all my data to numerical than  making the clustering in order to have a classification, but how to rely my PCAmix analysis with clustering, because I lost a lot of time in developing and analysing results? coulg give me some advice please

Comment: Again, PCAmix does not do classification. Latent class mixture models do. Find an R module for this type of model.